# Macro to concatenate two columns based on header values

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation

I have two columns in an Excel spreadsheet containing many columns. I would like to merge these two columns, but their location in the sheet may vary. This means that I need to utilize the first row column headers to determine which two columns to concatenate. I would like the result to be added as the next column in the sheet.

For example, where "Brand", "Line, and "Product" are in row 1 as column headers, the macro should search for the value in "Brand" and concatenates it with the value in "Model" and puts the result in an inserted column in the sheet (in this case D, but that could change depending on the number of columns). I can't use column or cell references because the position of the Brand and Model columns might change, as well as the number of columns:

A      |     B          |    C                 |
Brand      |     Line      |   Model           |
Pentax    |  Camera   |    K-30            |
Honda     |     Auto     |  Accord          |
Apple      | Computer | MacBook Air |

Here's what I've tried:

```
Sub Insrt()
    Dim Model As Range
    Dim Brand As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set Brand = Rows(1).Find(what:="Brand", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set Model = Rows(1).Find(what:="Model", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Found Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Brand.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Model.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    Cells(1, Model.Column + 1).Value = "Concatenated_Value"
    Range(Cells(2, Model.Column + 1), Cells(LastRow, Model.Column + 1)).Formula = "=A2&C2"
End Sub
```

The problem with this approach is that my formula is specifically concatenating columns A & C. Yet, Brand and Model might not be in those specific columns every time - in the future, they may shift locations. How can I improve this so that I'm not explicitly calling out columns A and C, and instead utilize the column headers?

Comment: You need to offset from A, based on the match on row 1, so =offset(a1,0,match("Brand",1:1,0)-1)&offset(a1,0,match("Line",1:1,0)-1) and so on.

Comment: Sorry, but I probably wasn't clear enough. I'm looking for a way to do this in a macro.

Comment: Then you will need show some effort on your part. SO is not a code for me service. We will help debug any code you currently have, but in general we will not write it for you

Comment: Thanks Scott, I appreciate the feedback. I've made some improvements to the question above.

Comment: See my edit for your formula rescemen .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use Index/Match:

```
=F2 & " " &INDEX(A:C,MATCH(F2,A:A,0),MATCH("Model",1:1,0))
```

[image]

No matter where "Model" ends up it will find the correct column.

For VBA. Change formula to

```
"=" & Cells(2,brand.column).address(0,0) & "&" & Cells(2,model.column).address(0,0)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=HLOOKUP("Brand",A:C,ROW(),0) & " " & HLOOKUP("Model",A:C,ROW(),0)
```

Comment: I would avoid the Indirect() it is a Volatile function.  Which means every time something on the sheet changes it will recalculate regardless if what changed is in the formula or not.

Comment: Great point, I didn't know Indirect was volatile.  Thanks, updated.

Comment: Hate to tell you this but so is OFFSET.  See [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx) for a list.  You will need to scroll down a little to find it.

Comment: Well I'll be.  Thanks for commenting, I had no idea.  (weird considering it's just a method of range that returns another range)

Answer (score 0):

I modded the code in the edited original question.

1- Option Explicit always a good idea.

2- Factored out the 2 column header searches, more DRY especially if more columns are ever needed to be added to be found.

2.a- Also the 'If Found Is Nothing Then' test didn't work, at least not on my box. And even if it had worked it gave no message. Silent failure might be OK, but often is not OK.  Now any not-found header gives a message.

2.b- Added MatchCase:=True to Find() maybe that change is not what is wanted, but does show why DRY code (Don't Repeat Yourself) helps. If you don't like that change cool you only edit one place to change it back, not 2, 3, or 4 places edited one for each header being found.

3- One answer had the snippet 'Cells(2,brand.column).address(0,0)' but the Address() method on Range object starts with capital A but Excel ADDRESS function is all caps. ADDRESS function docs say ADDRESS(0,0) is an OK call but Address(0,0) method on Range object docs say the two 0 values are variants looked at by Address() as True or not.

I modded to .Address(RowAbsolute:=False) so don't have to understand a 0 as False, and also we want ColumnAbsolute as True which is the default. We want one absolute, one relative so it confusing they are both the same when coded address(0,0)

4- The variable Formula9 is only there to make debugging easier. It could be edited out after debugging. On other hand, there is repetition in how it is assigned 'Cells(2, Brand.Column).Address(RowAbsolute:=False)'

So maybe a Function to factor out 'Cells(x,y).Address(RowAbsolute:=False)' would be more DRY.

How many temp variables to leave in, how much to factor out to make code more DRY are judgement calls.

```
Option Explicit
Function FindOrMsg(toFind As String) As Range
    Dim Rtn As Range
    Set Rtn = Rows(1).Find(what:=toFind, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                           lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    Set FindOrMsg = Rtn
    If Rtn Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Header '" & toFind & "' not found"
End Function

Sub Macro1()
    Dim Model As Range
    Dim Brand As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Set Brand = FindOrMsg("Brand")
    Set Model = FindOrMsg("Model")
    If (Brand Is Nothing) Or (Model Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Brand.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Model.Offset(, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
    Cells(1, Model.Column + 1).Value = "Concatenated_Value"

    Dim Formula9
    Formula9 = "=" & Cells(2, Brand.Column).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & "&" _
                   & Cells(2, Model.Column).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ""
    Range(Cells(2, Model.Column + 1), Cells(LastRow, Model.Column + 1)).Formula = Formula9
End Sub
```